# My device not connecting to IBM Watson using contiki

Tags: mqtt, contiki, watson-iot

I am trying to connect and publish data to IBM watson. I have registered in IBM watson and also registered my deivce there. I do this using contiki web demo example(cc26xx-web-demo) with MQTT protocol.

The hardware modules I am using are CC1310 Launchpad and weptech gateway module. I am able connect and see my device using "quickstart". But when I try to connect the registered device with orgId and auth-Token, it is not connecting. Device is getting registered and trying to connect. But not getting connected.

Comment: Please let us know your 6 character org ID so we can check the logs for authentication errors.  Also, new Watson IoT Platform services require that devices connect securely over TLS. Check your service by going to Security > Connection Security and changing the default rule (e.g., to TLS Optional) to see if that is why you are failing.

Comment: the org id is '7ovolo'

Comment: Was the TLS security set to optional on your service? is this the code you are using? https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/cc26xx/cc26xx-web-demo/mqtt-client.c   Did you manually register your device?  It may be helpful to open a support ticket to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that the URL is correct:

URL: org_id.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com
Where org_id is the ID of your Watson IoT Platform organization.